# Flat Assembler: How do I get the address of an label?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

How do I get the address of a label?

I want to get the address of a label in flat assembler without adding extra code

example:

```
label1:  ;is at adress 0
db 1h,2h,3h,4h,5h  ;some data

label2: is at address 5 because label1 has 5 bytes of data
```

I could print the address to the console screen but that adds size to the program and changes the result.

I'm aware of just using the label but I want the raw address number.

Comment: Use a debugger or something like `objdump` to get the address from the symbol table.  Label addresses aren't stored anywhere outside the symbol table if you don't use them (e.g. as a jump target, load/store address, immediate operand, or as data (e.g. `.dd label2`).

Comment: Ok.  There was still time to modify my first comment and delete the now-obsolete ones.  Note that it would be more accurate to say there are 5 bytes of data between `label1` and `label2`; labels don't have an associated size (unless you're using MASM or TASM, where the db/dw/dd after a label magically implies operand-size for instructions that use that label in a memory operand).

Comment: Anyway, just to clarify, you don't want to get the address into a register or into memory inside the program, right?  You want it printed on your screen somehow, separately from running your program?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want

Comment: Make the label public, generate a object file instead of an exectuable, use a linker to create the executable and have the linker generate a map file. That map file will tell you the address of the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Solution:

i just put all symbols at the very end of the assembly file and then looked at it with an hex editor:

example:

```
label1: ;example label (can be anywhere)
;...
;... My Programm
;...

;the end of the program
db 0h ;just some spacer
dw label1
```

Comment: yup, that works and shouldn't disturb the layout of previous code.  If FASM has an ALIGN directive, that could make the block of addresses easy to find, and aligned at the start of a line of hex dump output.  You can probably tell from my answer that I don't know anything about FASM specifically, and mostly use NASM/YASM on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Build your program with debug symbols, so the symbol table (metadata) in the object file includes the addresses of all the labels.

Then you can use `objdump -t` to dump the symbol table of the executable, or any other program that does the same thing.

---

Other than the symbol table, label addresses will be in the binary embedded into instructions, e.g. in absolute addressing modes for addressing modes, immediate operands, or as data (e.g. `.dd label2`).  Normal jumps use a relative encoding, so you won't find the absolute symbol address in the instruction encoding for jumps.

TL:DR: disassembling the binary to find absolute addresses is possible, but only for labels used that way, so the symbol table is way more convenient.

---

If you're assembling a flat binary (like a boot sector), there is no symbol table in the file format.  So you're dependent on having FASM print symbol info for you, when you use a command-line option to do that.  I googled and found that [there's a `-s` option](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=9792) to write a `.fas` symbol-info debug output file.

Comment: I'm not sure if FASM supports debug symbols and that `.fas` file isn't human readable unfortunately.